# Are there animal species who would sacrifice their lives to save their offspring?

Tags: zoology, animal-psychology

In the comment section of YouTube animal videos, there are people who say that animal mothers love their offspring very much as if human mothers do. But are there actual animal species whose parents are willing to lose their lives to save their offspring's lives?

Thinking purely in the perspective of spreading its genes more, it seems to me that it will be better to save the parent's own life and produce more offspring in the future than losing his or her life to save current batch of offspring, so I cannot think animals have that much "love" for their offspring, but it could be wrong.

Also, exclude the species that reproduce and automatically die afterwards, like salmon.

Comment: Why exclude the species which are the clearest examples of the circumstances you describe? Especially because I'd wager that a majority of animal species follow that pattern.

Comment: Is it actually true that human parents are willing to sacrifice their lives to save their children? It's a saying that gets a lot of advertisement, but does data actually back it up?

Comment: animals are willing to kill to save their offspring and are at the risk of getting killed by doing so.i think that it is fairly close to sacrfice their life?

Comment: The pelican is often used in Christian symbolism because of the belief that a mother pelican will kill herself to feed her brood. However, I'm having trouble finding any zoological / scholarly sources that confirm or refute this phenomenon.

Comment: In support of the other side of the argument, pelicans have been observed [cannibalising their own chicks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelican#Feeding).

Comment: "*Thinking purely in the perspective of spreading its genes more, it seems to me that it will be better to save the parent's own life*" My understanding is that this tends to be the case not that long ago when people had many more children than they do now and infant mortality was much higher. At that time, it was arguable that losing your spouse was more traumatic than losing your child. Also social insects routinely sacrifice themselves to save their progeny.

Comment: @trondhansen Yeah, tell me an example of a species that actually takes very real danger to its own life to save its children.

Comment: @DKNguyen The social insects example, I think, is not applicable here, because they are not parents but copies. That is, the individual who sacrifices itself have the same genes as the ones that it saves. I was talking more about parents whose children have only 50% of one parent.

Comment: Large herding animals do this all the time. Surround the weak and young

Comment: Plovers fake injury to draw predators away from their nest, drawing the attention/interest of the predator to themselves. Parents die trying to save their kids somewhere in the world all the time: parents drown holding the child above them, push their kids out of the way of oncoming traffic, mothers forgoing chemotherapy while pregnant and allowing the cancer to advance and become fatal, etc. Animals **may** not love their offspring in the same way, but they do love them (read Jane Goodall's work.) But I suspect you'll reject any answer just for the sake of argument.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Brings up a thought...you probably need to look at animals that live in communities and can rear the orphaned offspring. The parent sacrificing itself to save an offspring is pointless if all the offspring die. I am unsure if a single parent could do the job unless that was the normal arrangement for that animal, but in that case it is also less likely, though not impossible, that the non-caregiving parent would be around to sacrifice itself in the first place. If just you and your 5 year old live in an isolated cabin in the woods, it is quite pointless to sacrifice yourself.

Comment: Which also brings up the fact that dying in an attempt to save your offspring is not the same as willingly sacrificing yourself so your offspring lives on. In that respect, it may be impossible to know what an animal's intentions were because you do not know how they think since you are not that animal.

Comment: For the human side, if wikipedia is to be held reputable in that matter ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infanticide_(zoology)) and [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infanticide)), filial infanticide has been observed in humans as a form of population control in situation of scarcity. It was quite common, it was transversal to all cultures and it had been there since before the invention of agriculture. Concerning sex-selective infanticide, I take the liberty to remark that a reasoning like "I can raise another two sons, but not a second daughter" is a rather sophisticated take on scarcity.